# Python os.system different behavior notepad vs excel

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, operating-system

The following code assumes there are files called test.txt and test.xlsx in C:\Temp on a windows 10 system. If you enter note, notepad is opened and the Tkinter gui is locked up until you close the test.txt file. If you choose ss, test.xlsx is opened as expected but the gui does not lock up. I know that I could fix the notepad issue by opening it in a task but I am perplexed by the differing behavior and wonder which behavior is correcct for os.system.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Workout Program')
root.geometry('950x600')
root.configure(background='ivory3')

def get_choice():
    choice = Entry_Choice.get()
    if choice == "note":
       os.system("notepad C:\\Temp\\test.txt")
    elif choice == "ss":
       os.system("start excel C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx" )
    else:
       print("Invalid choice")

Label_Choice=tk.Label(root,text="Choose note or ss",
                 font="Times 14 bold", padx=35, relief="ridge", bd=10,
                 bg="white")
Label_Choice.grid(row=0, column=0)

Entry_Choice=tk.Entry(root,width=10,bg="white",
                    font="Times 16 bold", relief=tk.SUNKEN, bd=10)
Entry_Choice.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button_Choice = tk.Button(root, text="Enter",
                  width=15, bg="grey", fg="white",
                  font="Times 12 bold", relief="raised", bd=10,
                  command=get_choice)
Button_Choice.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `start` command to run `notepad`, the same way you execute `excel`?

Comment: Your right, I can't believe I missed that. So I guess "start", starts a subprocess while without it it runs in the currevt process. Makes sense,